# Get code completion of Typedef Objective-C blocks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c-blocks

I'm creating a class where it's methods take blocks as parameters for success and failure actions. Since I'm reusing the blocks in many of my methods, I created Typedefs for each of them...

```
typedef void (^Success)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *__nonnull __strong operation, id __nonnull __strong responseObject);
typedef void (^Failure)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *__nonnull __strong operation, NSError *__nonnull __strong error);
```

Then I use them in a method header like this...

```
- (void)show:(nonnull NSString *)objectId 
     success:(nullable Success)success 
     failure:(nullable Failure)failure;
```

The blocks work as expected, but I lose the code completion (IntelliSense) that I would have had, were I not using Typedefs.

**Without Typedefs**
[image: Without Typedefs]

**With Typedefs**
[image: With Typedefs]

Is there any way to get the code completion when using Typedef blocks? What is the best practice to expose the Typedef syntax to the user of the class?

Comment: Odd; Xcode expands them for me here. What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Whelp, that appears to have been the issue. I was working on a computer that was still running 6.3. Tried it out on Xcode 7 and code completion worked as expected. Thanks for pointing that out.